# Getting error while converting VMX to OVF format

Tags: type-conversion, virtual-machine, vmware, esx, ovf

I am trying to convert .vmx to OVF format using OVFtool. I am following the below steps:

- Copying .vmx and .vmdk file using "scp" command from ESX server to
  one linux box.
- On linux box, executed command [# ovftool myVM.vmx myOVF.ovf] from
  the location where .vmx and .vmdk are present. I get error as below:

  ```
  Opening VMX source: myVM.vmx
  Error: Failed to open disk: myVM.vmdk
  Completed with errors
  ```

Please can anyone suggest

I have also noticed that on ESX there are 2-3 .vmdk files of same VM, myVM-flat.vmdk, myVM.vmdk, myVM-000001.vmdk. Do I need to copy all .vmdk files to linux box and then convert file format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have answered the question yourself :). Yes you need to copy all the files e.g myVM-000001.vmdk, myVM-flat.vmdk, myVM.vmdk to your location and then do the conversion.